# Rails : model.save returns false but models.errors is an empty hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a model object on which .save is returning false.  It subsequently has a .errors property which is an empty hash.  Shouldn't the hash contain a list of what went wrong?  How else can I determine why the save is not working?

TY,
Fred

Answer (score 12):

This means that one of your callbacks is probably stopping the save, but isn't listing a validation error.

Check the return values, especially of any `before_` callbacks and make sure that they are not returning `false`

If they return `false`, then active record will stop future callbacks and return false from the save.

You can read a little bit about it [here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks.html) under "canceling callbacks"

Comment: I only have one before :save method which just strips some whitespace.  I commented that out, but still have the same problem, error messages are empty.

Comment: I also tried commenting out all the callbacks for the model class, but still get the same result, no error information.

Comment: Does `valid?` also return false?

Comment: Yes it does, does that help diagnose things?

Comment: Are you including any modules in the model? Anything like paperclip or carrierwave?

Comment: No not including anything, just have the bare model.

Comment: There are no associations.

Comment: Please guys can you suggest anything else, getting pretty desperate here.

Comment: I can't think of much else, would it be possible for you to post your model code?

Answer (score 2):

1) Disable **before_create, before_save, before_update** and check where it saves the day

2) If rollback was caused by one of those methods, check that those methods return true when you don't plan to rollback.

For example if you set default value for boolean field to avoid nil, you would probably do it this way

```
def set_defaults_before_create
  self.my_boolean_field ||= false
end
```

In this example method **set_defaults_before_create** always returns **false** and thus rollbacks your transaction. So refactor it to return true

```
def set_defaults_before_create
  self.my_boolean_field ||= false
  true
end
```